# reading strand (+, -) column with fread, data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use fread to read a genome alignment into a `data.table` in R. Here's a snapshot of the alignment file:

```
USI-EAS28:1:100:1786:674#0/1    +   1_maternal  68326824      CTCAATTATACTGAAAGAAACACAATATATCATA    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   
USI-EAS28:1:100:1786:940#0/1    +   16_maternal 11407541    CTATTAGTGACCTGCTGTGGGACCTTGGGATGGT  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   
USI-EAS28:1:100:1786:705#0/1    +   1_maternal  63849584    CTGAGGGTTTGTGTCAGGAAGGGGTGTGGAATTG  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   0:T>C
USI-EAS28:1:100:1786:1168#0/1   -   5_maternal  31381649    GCATCATTCATGAAACAATTTTCAAGAGAGGAAA  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   
 USI-EAS28:1:100:1787:582#0/1   +   10_maternal 54587781    CTACAATAATAATAGGGGACTAAAACACCCCACT  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   
 USI-EAS28:1:100:1787:62#0/1    +   10_maternal 70390747     CTATTTGCTACTGAATTGTTAATTTTAAAACAGT IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   
 USI-EAS28:1:100:1788:573#0/1   -   7_maternal  92583837     CACTGTCAACATTAGACAGACCAATGAGACAAAG IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   
 USI-EAS28:1:100:1788:854#0/1   +   7_maternal  129611206    GTTTGTTTTTTTTTTTGAGATGGAGTCTCATTTT IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   32:C>T
 USI-EAS28:1:100:1788:185#0/1   -   13_maternal 23694307    CAAACAAACTCAAAATGGACTATCGACTGAAAAA  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   
 USI-EAS28:1:100:1788:1339#0/1  -   13_maternal 33699510    TTAACTCTAGTTTTTAGGGATTGCAAATTAGACG  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  0   0:A>G
```

The second column reports the strand the read aligns to (`+` is forward, `-` is reverse). Unfortunately fread is trying to read this column into an integer, assigning the value always to 0. This column should be read as a character, or even a boolean, for that matter. Trying to play with arguments `sep` and `sep2` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Now fixed in v1.8.9 commit 849. `+` and `-` are now read as character, test added.

Btw, we are also intending to add `colClasses` so that you can override the column type that `fread` detects. The outstanding to do list relating to `fread` is at the top of the source file here :
https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/src/fread.c?view=markup&root=datatable

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. Actually colClasses was what first came to mind, but as you know, it only works as an argument to read.table; looking forward to it being also an argument to fread!

Comment: @AlvaroGonzalez Hi. Didn't need `colClasses` actually. If there's no digit after `+` or `-` it now reads it as `character`. Available from the [R-Forge repo](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240) usually within a few hours (when it says rev 849 and status: current).

Comment: It runs like a breeze, @MatthewDowle. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlvaroGonzalez No problem, thanks for highlighting it. Please +1 (click the grey triangle above 0 to turn it orange) and also accept this answer (click the big white tick to turn it green).