# fread not recognizing a bare + or - as a character field

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I was trying fread on some files that look like this and are bout 2GB in size:

```
head file.bed
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     1       0
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     2       0
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     3       0
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     4       0
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     5       0
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     6       0
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     7       0
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     8       0
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     9       0
chr1    19922471        19924471        +       NM_001204088    tss     10      0
```

Column 4 also has a similar number of "-". Reading in R the +/- are turned into 0:

```
cov.data <- fread(file)
head(cov.data)
     V1       V2       V3 V4           V5  V6 V7 V8
1: chr1 19922471 19924471  0 NM_001204088 tss  1  1
2: chr1 19922471 19924471  0 NM_001204088 tss  2  1
3: chr1 19922471 19924471  0 NM_001204088 tss  3  1
4: chr1 19922471 19924471  0 NM_001204088 tss  4  1
5: chr1 19922471 19924471  0 NM_001204088 tss  5  1
6: chr1 19922471 19924471  0 NM_001204088 tss  6  0
```

I've looked in the documentation but not figure out why. Any suggestions? Could it be a bug since fread is still under development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

First, if your file is with quotes, that is, if your column for `strand` is `"+"` or `"-"`, then `fread` from `data.table` version 1.8.8 will read correctly.

Second, [this has been rectified in `data.table` version 1.8.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388714/reading-strand-column-with-fread-data-table-package), which you can install using:

```
install.packages("data.table",repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")
```

If necessary, you can install `devtools` and then use `dev_mode(TRUE)` to go into development mode and then install `data.table` there so that it doesn't hinder your normal running of `data.table` 1.8.8.

Copy/paste of relevant Change log from 1.8.9:

```
NEW FEATURES
o  fread :
   * If some column names are blank they are now given default names rather than causing
       the header row to be read as a data row. Thanks to Simon Judes for suggesting.

   * "+" and "-" are now read as character rather than integer 0. Thanks to Alvaro Gonzalez for reporting.
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388714/reading-strand-column-with-fread-data-table-package

....
```

Comment: I doubt that many people will hit upon this behavior, but it's good to hear that it's been fixed.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, Yes. Mostly bioinformaticians/computational biologists I suppose. I ran into the same issue as well.

Comment: Thanks @Arun. Great to hear that this has been fixed since fread will save several minutes in each file. Regarding your question, the + and - are not quoted on my original files and you guessed right: I am a bioinformatician :)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the static function `Strtoll` in `fread.c` (in the `data.table` 1.8.8 source) scans for a leading `+` or `-`, and also ensures that at least one character has been consumed to determine if it has scanned an integer.

The logic then starts with an accumulator of 0, and multiplies this by 10 and adds in each digit.  No non-digits are found, so the function returns TRUE.

Looks like a bug.